# In Js, why document object is displayed in such a different manner unlike other objects?

Tags: javascript, object, dom, ecmascript-6

if we do:`console.log(typeof document)` we'll know *document* is an *object*

I suppose object should be shown in format:

```
 object_name{property1:value1,property2:value2,...}
```

Anyway, for *document object* if we simply do `console.log(document)` then we'll be shown results in following format :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Why is document displayed in such a peculiar manner ?

Comment: Unsure why, window.document is a reference to the document. It is not an object. It acts just like when you log a div or any other html element.

Comment: `document` is not like "other objects"; it is an API exposed to the JavaScript realm by the browser. It's unique.

Comment: There is no standard for how browsers represent values in the console. For many objects that are somehow related to the DOM, an HTML representation of them is logged. But browser can go about this however they want.

Comment: The same reason that `console.log(document.getElementById("foo"))` doesn't render a classical object view.

Comment: It's not really a quirk of browsers either, there's no guarantee any javascript `console.log` implementation will print key-value pairs of all their objects. For example printing `Buffer` in `node` will output a more useful visualization of the `Buffer` object. It's just deemed more useful.

Answer (score 0):

For dom element `console.log` will give them a special treatment while displaying them & they're displayed in a tree structure .To display DOM element as property and value pairs we can use `console.dir`

**Further below are articles which consolidates this same issues:**
1.[what is console.dir and why use it ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#difference_between_log_and_dir)
2.[unusual behaviour of dom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66211098/13415580)