# Unexpected behaviour of document object in Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dom, frontend

Despite the `document` being an object, how are we still accessing items in `document.forms` by indexing it, as if it was an array?

E.g.: `document.forms[1]` gives us

```html
<form><input tags>...</form>
```

Also if we do `console.log(document.forms)` then we can nowhere find the actual `<form></form>` element which is returned to us by `document.forms[1]`

Then how is this all working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What does `console.log(document.forms)` do, and what does it return?

`document.forms` is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). A HTMLCollection is like an array in that is has a `.length` and is accessible via index (like `document.forms[1]`).

Another way to look at objects is with `console.dir()` ([See documentation about `console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#difference_between_log_and_dir))
This function is like `console.log`, but it will show the results in a more object-like way.

Example:

```js
console.dir(document.forms)
> HTMLCollection(2)
  > 0: form#search...
  > 1: form#post-form
    length: 2
  > post-form: form#post-form
  > search: form#search
```

This seems more like the output you are expecting.

Another thing to note is that different browsers will display the results of `console.log` differently.

Comment: Yes console.dir()  explained it exactly.
Thanx a huge deal ,Man